# Lowercase django query

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to do the following without doing raw sql or post-processing in django?

```
dict(Language.objects.values_list('code' LOWER(),'language'))
```

Comment: What is suposed to be ``LOWER()`` ?

Comment: @Zulu the 'code' field should be tolower

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This can be done in Django 1.8+ by importing the [`Lower`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#lower) database function.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
qs = Language.objects.annotate(code_lower=Lower('code')) # annotate each item in the queryset with the code_lower
values = qs.values_list('code_lower', 'language')
dictionary = dict(values)
```

I've split the answer into several lines for readability, you can collapse into a one liner if you prefer.

Comment: `Lower` is by default: `from django.db.models.functions import Lower`. Also, you can just write `Lower('field')`.